# Python ternary expression

Tags: python, ternary-operator

So here's a simple object creation and assignment using a 1 line ternary expression in Java.

```
Interval newInterval = previous.end <= current.end ? new Interval(previous.start, current.end : new Interval(previous.start, previous.end)
```

The python equivalent is,

```
new_interval = Interval(previous.start, current.end) if previous.end <= current.end else Interval(previous.start, previous.end)
```

My question is there a more `pythonic` way to write this?

Comment: `new_interval = Interval(previous.start, current.end if previous.end <= current.end else previous.end)` seems more reasonable to me (in both languages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The form I'd like more is probably

```
new_interval = Interval(previous.start, max(current.end, previous.end))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more Pythonic:

```
start = previous.start
end = max(current.end, previous.end)
new_interval = Interval(start, end)
```